# Получить название группы "Администраторы" windows

Tags: windows, delphi, wmi

В чем именно проблема : создаю нового пользователя, с помощью net.exe, и нужно его перенести в группу администраторы, но проблема в том, что, в зависимости от языка, группа может называться "Администраторы" (для рус) или "Administators" (для англ).

Можно как-то сразу определить точное название группы админа?

Как вариант, узнать язык в ОС, а там уже выбирать, но это не самое лучшее решение. Может быть, есть еще варианты ?

Язык: delphi

```
WinExec('cmd /c "net user USERAD admin /add /ACTIVE:YES"', SW_HIDE);
WinExec('cmd /c "net localgroup Администраторы USERAD /add"', SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: код то ваш где? как создаете, как в группу добавляете?

Comment: @teran простите, добавил

Comment: а [напрямую](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2445264/1216425) то не хотите?

Comment: @teran а можно как-то без исп сторонник библиотек ? (тип Jedi )

Comment: "net localgroup %Administrators% %NAME% /add" ?

Comment: @Nikolay.OAMP неа, дает ошибку, что такой группы не существует

Comment: сама библиотека и не нужна. Если в стандартной поставки делфи нет этих заголовочных файлов, то можно скачать их из JEDI либо еще где найти, либо самому переписать, согласно тому что написано на MSDN.

Comment: @teran при попытке установить jedi вылазит ошибка `C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Add_User\jcl-2.4.1.4571\experts\projectanalyzer\JclProjectAnalyzerFrm.pas(497) Error: Statement expected but 'PROCEDURE' found
JclProjectAnalysisExpert.dpk(54) Fatal: Could not compile used unit '..\..\experts\projectanalyzer\JclProjectAnalyzerFrm.pas'
Compilation failure
...failed.`

а JclWin32.pas тащит за собой кучу других файлов

Comment: @teran перенес все необходимые файлы для JclWin32, запустил проект (с учетом изменений в комментариях), но юзер так и не создался (( [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/CeymVMNq)

Comment: дак не тащите все то оттуда. вам нужны пара сигнатур методов и описание нескольких структур только

Comment: @teran суть не в этом, проблема в том, что учетка все равно не создается

Comment: Кстати, если мне не изменяет память, net - это приложение net.exe, а не команда, зачем вы его через cmd вызываете?

Comment: да, я знаю, я переделал его и вызываю ехе с параметрами, но и этот способ не хуже, в винде путь к этому ехе записан изначально и смысла в ввода полного пути до ехе не имеет большого смысла, можно и с консолькой работать, тут кому как нравится )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На правах шутки можно так (хотя код рабочий, просто подход, что называется, "от балды" :) ):

```
@set AdminName=Administrators
@net user %AdminName% 2>&1
@IF ERRORLEVEL 1 set AdminName=Администраторы  >nul
@echo %AdminName%
```

Данный код поместить в BAT-файл (в 866 кодировке, иначе выводиться будут кракозябры). Затем используйте %AdminName% для net.exe.

Более серьезно так (подключаем WMI, куда мы без него, вспоминая, что админы имеют всегда `SID = 544`):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "wmic=wmic group where sid="S-1-5-32-544" get name /value"
for /f %%i in (' "%wmic%" ') do 1>nul set "%%i"
echo %name%
```

Аналогично, используйте %name% в своих целях в дальнейшем.

Ну, и если всё же Delphi, то однозначно WMI. Привожу универсальный код для вызова большинства запросов к WMI в Delphi:

```
function GetWMIstring(wmiHost, root, wmiClass, wmiProperty: string): string;
var
  objWMIService : OLEVariant;
  colItems      : OLEVariant;
  colItem       : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;

  function GetWMIObject(const objectName: String): IDispatch;
  var
    chEaten: Integer;
    BindCtx: IBindCtx;
    Moniker: IMoniker;
  begin
    OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, bindCtx));
    OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(BindCtx, StringToOleStr(objectName), chEaten, Moniker));
    OleCheck(Moniker.BindToObject(BindCtx, nil, IDispatch, Result));
  end;

begin
  objWMIService := GetWMIObject(Format('winmgmts:\\%s\%s',[wmiHost,root]));
  colItems      := objWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT * FROM %s',[wmiClass]),'WQL',0);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(colItems._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, colItem, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
     Result:=colItem.Properties_.Item(wmiProperty, 0); //работает только с единичным откликом, если результат массив, надо добавлять работу с TStringList.
  end;
end;
```

используем функцию затем так:

```
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
     AdminGroupName:=GetWMIstring('.', 'root\CIMV2', 'Win32_Group where SID="S-1-5-32-544"','Caption');
    finally
    CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
        // обработка ошибок
    end;
  end;
```

И всё - название группы у нас в кармане. По-хорошему, и добавить пользователя можно через Delphi :) , но если вам нравится net.exe, то используйте его.

Comment: спасибо )) я уже не помню, как я решил тогда эту задачу, но ваш ответ явно не будет лишним. спасибо

Comment: Добавить пользователя через Jedi?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Я предпочту NetUserAdd :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Почему? Быстрее?