# Как узнать язык операционной системы Windows?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, локаль

Как программно узнать язык операционной системы Windows (начиная с Windows XP)?

Интересует именно язык системы - то есть язык, на котором Windows общается с пользователем программы, а не выбранная страна или раскладка клавиатуры и т.п. Условно говоря, надо узнать на каком языке написано название "My Computer" или "Мой Компьютер" или "Mój Komputer". Формат полученного обозначения не так важен (ISO или англ.текст или локализованый текст).

*Мысли вслух:

Попробовал несколько вариантов, включая `GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT..`, `GetSystemDefaultLangID`, `GetUserDefaultLangID`, но ни один из них не вернул мне локаль моей ОС (англ.), а вернул `Russian`. пока что единственная правдоподобная зацепка - `hklm\system\controlset001\control\nls\language\Installlanguage`, но тогда непонятно, почему Install Language один (англ.), а Default другой (рус.), при том что ОС со мной общается на английском.*

Comment: AFAIK, LangID функции относятся к языку ввода. Т.е. если языком ввода по-умолчанию стоит русский, то они и возвращают русский. И это не имеет никакого отношения к языку системы. А вам нужна функция [GetSystemDefaultUILanguage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd318123(v=vs.85).aspx). Но вообще всё это [уже давно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322578/win32-api-for-getting-the-languagelocalization-info-of-the-os) есть на SO (только там не тот ответ отмечен правильным).

Comment: У меня по умолчанию стоит английский, а они все равно русский возвращали .. так что ответ на вопрос пока скорее мутный, чем ясный

Comment: [`GetUserDefaultUILanguage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd318137(v=vs.85).aspx) вроде оно?

Comment: @teran если запостите с объяснением,что это такое и как отличается от остальных - приму

Comment: @Kromster да я даже не знаю, оно это или нет. что нагуглилось и не увидел среди ваших вариантов написал. я сейчас больше в вэб-области сосредоточен, так что даже проверять это все негде, поэтому какой ответ написать толковый возможности нет.

Comment: В теории, это можно решить и не дельфийскими (внешними, то бишь) методами :) Более того, даже "хулиганскими" вроде такого: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662373/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для относительно новых версий Delphi можно воспользоваться вызовом   `GetUserDefaultUILanguage` из модуля WinAPI.Windows (возвращает значение языка интерфейса, выбранное **текущим** пользователем):

```
var
  i: integer
<...>
 i := Lo(GetUserDefaultUILanguage); // нижнего байта достаточно для определения языка, вида надписей на кнопках и т.п.
// Это может быть не так для экзотических языков, но с ними я не сталкивался

 case i of
   $19: // русский
 end;
```

Вот [список ряда языков, возвращаемых в нижнем байте](https://pastebin.com/W59jJDu7) или же [оф. список от Майкрософт](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd318693(v=vs.85).aspx)

Для старых версий Delphi придётся самостоятельно определить `GetUserDefaultUILanguage` из kernel32.dll, например, так:

```
function GetSystemDefaultUILanguage: integer; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';
```

Поскольку @teran первым указал на функцию, ответ можно оформить, как общий.